# Get value of variable passed to spawn_id in Expect

Tags: ssh, expect

I've managed to write a simple expect script to backup multiple router configs. This works fine but takes some time slow when the list of devices grows.

I tried to find an a way to spawn SSH sessions simultaneously and came across an [article](https://community.activestate.com/forum-topic/spawning-multiple-telnet-sessions-expect) that goes:

```
# spawn all connections
foreach conn $allconnections {

spawn telnet $conn
lappend spawn_id_list $spawn_id

}

# run expect script for all connections individually
foreach id $spawn_id_list {

# this is important - for unknown (to me) reasons
set spawn_id $id

send "your_send_message"
expect "your_expect_pattern"

}
```

This seems to work but I am now faced with another challenge in creating a backup file named after the actual device. When $conn is passed to spawn_id and I create the backup file based on $id_configs.txt, I only get "expN" where N is a number which increments as each line on the device list is read. I've been experimenting on how to get the actual $id value back to use as filename but have yet to find a solution.

Appreciate any input from you guys. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
% set pid [spawn telnet xx.xx.xxx.xx]
spawn telnet xx.xx.xxx.xx
29353
% set pid
29353
```

The `spawn` returns process id of whatsoever program being spawned. You can save that in a variable and use it further.